# clearteam explorer as a plugin to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

I am trying to configure Clearteam explorer in eclipse 3.5.

- I downloaded Eclipse 3.5
- installed GEF plugin.
- Installed clearcase plugin from sourceforge.
  http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/eclipse-ccase/index.php?title=Installation
- Installed clearcase 8.0 in machine and made my machine act as a registry server. Clearcase 8 is included with Clearteam explorer (CCRC).
- here is the process for installing CTE for eclipse
  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccrc_eclipse.htm
- I gave my machine //hostname/ccrc/update as given in the doc, but it isnt working.
- There is also another way to give the path as - file:/c:/my repository path... even this way its not working. it is showing an error as repository not fount at ...file:/c:/my repository path

Some Doubts which may help in resolving problems:

- Will there be any plugin inside Clearcase which i can use for eclipse.
- I did not install CCRC WAN server into my machine as am using my machine as a registry server. Is it Mandatroy to install CCRC WAN.
- If i want to install CCRC WAN i need to install IBM HTTP server and websphere along with that.

Does this make any impact on the current issue.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the eclipse--case plugin couldn't possibly work with the ClearTeam 8.x new release of ClearCase.

[eclipse-ccase, like the IBM ClearCase plugin for Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/eclipse-ccase/index.php?title=Feature_comparison_to_the_IBM_ClearCase_plugin) are for a full ClearCase 6.x - 7.x installation, not for CCRC (7.2) or ClearTeam (8.x).

With ClearCase 8.0, what you would need to follow is the IBM article
"[Installation of ClearTeam Explorer into an existing IDE (such as Eclipse SDK)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031012)"

[image: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24031012&aid=4]

Comment: Thanks alot.. I was actually trying with the Clearteam explorer included in Base clearcase 8. but niw i downloaded CTE 8 individually and tried. its working now.

Comment: @Raj great. Does my answer address your question, then?